# using cookies for login: code doesn't work in different pages

Tags: php, cookies, if-statement, authentication

I have 2 pages that both have the same code for checking whether if someone's logged in or not. In the index page it shows the username if the cookie for username is set. But and on the second page, the login page, it redirects back to index page if the username cookie is set. Here's the if statement that checks it:

login page:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    die();
}
```

index page:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
    echo '<p style=""> '.$_COOKIE['username'].'</p>';
}else{...}
```

that's pretty much the code in a nutshell. in the login page the redirect works fine, I've checked it with different pages. But in the index page, even though it's the exact same if statement, it doesn't work.

Is there a problem with the code, or is it a folder/server related issue?

Thanks,
O.N.

Comment: Did you use `session_set_cookie_params` to set the domain path ?

Comment: no, but isn't that same as using setcookie method?

Comment: If you place `print_r($_COOKIE); exit;` before the if...else statement on the index page, what do you get?

Comment: Array ( [PHPSESSID] => ipt3p4bd5kar832e7qlkrgoll2 )

Comment: Ah... so, unless I'm mistaken, the $_COOKIE is not storing/retrieving the 'username' variable. When does it get set?

Comment: Yeah I think that's might be the problem. The cookie gets set on a different page with this code:    setcookie("username", $username, $expTime);

Comment: In that case, after you do the setcookie... then run the debug code `print_r($_COOKIE); exit;` and see if it is being set. Also, I find the Firebug extension in Firefox useful for seeing which Cookie data has been successfully loaded in certain pages. This would be useful with on the index page in your situation.

Comment: check Apache error log. can cookie be saved ? ( the cookie folder is writable ? )

Comment: @shivan raptor, yeah, I didn't check the log but I know it is, it works in other websites on the same root. 
Paul I posted the result of the print_r up there in the comments